# Outdated job postings?

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs

Just now I clicked this

[image]

it took me to

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/55107/analyst-programmer-microsoft-dynamics-crm-net-university-of-oxford?a=15cX0Lk8o

but unfortunately I just "wasted my time" because I am 2 weeks late :O

[image]

Comment: I have no idea about the innerworkings of SO.careers, but I doubt this is a bug - seems like the people who created the job posting simply didn't remove it after their deadline expired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So that's a bad on the customer. They should have expired the listing before then. Thanks for the heads up though! I went ahead and expired it myself.