# Auto-expire careers adverts

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, jobs

Based on this post "[Outdated job postings?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231685/outdated-job-postings)" and my own personal experiences using Stack Overflow Careers.

I think it would beneficial, for users and advertisers, to require careers advertisers to specify an end date when creating job listings allowing the advert to expire automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that would be a great idea but it would take a huge amount of work on our end because of they way the system is currently setup. We currently sell listing in 30 day slots. (We do also offer 6 month and 1 year listings but those are in the minority).

Basically once a listing is started, the majority of the time they automatically expire after 30 days. Changing that to expire on a specific date would take a major re-write of how the products are managed on the back end.

Comment: I'll add while this is a lot of work, we are considering a system right now that works just like that.