# Careers outdated job ads

Tags: feature-request, jobs, advertising

Occasionally see ads with a closing date already passed. Just wondering is there a field holding job ad's valid-to date when employer submit a new job, so that outdated job can be filtered out?

Comment: Yeah, they are semi-useless noise, and oughta be automatically withdrawn by the system IMHO.

Comment: Do you have an example? There may be a few minutes of caching, but it shouldn't be very noticeable. It's possible there's a bug.

Comment: Where do you see a "close date" exactly?

Comment: Possible duplicate and/or related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231688/auto-expire-careers-adverts and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231685/outdated-job-postings

Comment: @DavidFullerton, two examples: [this one](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/58358/c-sharp-net-developer-bbc?a=19aL0g9hu&searchTerm=bbc) showing on the page this morning; and [this one](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/57464/software-developer-senior-software-developer-wellcome-trust-sanger?a=185bi9iRG) is on for now

Comment: The issue not a "bug" per se. We sell the majority of our listings in 30 day chunks. These are examples of a customer buy a 30 day job listing, having an expiration date 20 days into the 30 day run, and not expiring the listing.

Comment: @Juice well, OP here marked this as feature request not a bug. Can't you "force expire" a job listing on your side?

Comment: We can. This is why we also have a flagging system in place when visiting the listing.